If the $k-$th forward difference of the sequence $a_n$ is positive for every $k,$ then $a_n$ is at least an exponential sequence.
If $a_n>0,$ and $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an exponential sequence, that is, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\mu>1\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},$ then the $k-$th forward difference of the sequence $a_n$ is positive for every $k.$ I'm wondering what can be said about the converse of this statement. Something like,
"If the $k-$th forward difference of the sequence $a_n$ is positive for every $k,$ then $a_n$ is at least an exponential sequence, that is $\displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\mu>1$ ."
I'm not sure if this exact statement is true, but what are some more precise, well-known true statements of this flavour, along with some proof sketches?

Note sure if this is what you are looking for: If $a_n = \mu^n$ then (unless I made an error) $\Delta^k a_n = \mu^n(\mu-1)^k \ge (\mu-1)^k$, which is more than just stating that $\Delta^k a_n > 0$. Conversely, if $\Delta^k a_0 \ge (\mu-1)^k$ for all $k$ then $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \Delta^ka_0 \ge \mu^k$.

Let $c_0,c_1,\ldots$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{c_n}=0$. Then the series $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^k$ converges. Let $a_n=f(n)$. Uisng the mean value theorem, one can readily show that the $k$th difference sequence is a sequence of values of the $k$th derivative of $f$, hence always positive.
If $c_k=\frac1{k!}$, then $f(x)=e^x$ and we have exponential growth. However, $c_n$ may tend to zero much faster. Fore example with $c_k=\frac1{(k^2)!}$, you get a sequence $a_n$ that grows faster than any polynomial and yet slower than any exponential function.
